# SHT35 "[Errno 121] Remote I/O error" while performing test readings from SDA and SCL pins

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microcontroller, sensors

I ran into a quite big problem that I can't solve for past 3h on my Raspberry Pi 4B. I connected SHT35 that I bought from China as it supposed be connected: Vcc to 3V3, Gnd to Ground, SDA to SDA and SCL to SCL. I'm getting SHT35's address from console using "i2cdetect -y 1" but I can't get any readings while using a test code, that checks for state of SDA and SCL. All I'm getting is "[Errno 121] Remote I/O error".

However, while the program is running, when I use "i2cdetect -y 1" im getting proper reading for SDA and SCL which are 0, and then error continues.

Here's code that I'm using and screenshot that shows "proper" readings:

[image]

I've tried resoldering them to make them perfect and tried software related solutions (mostly libraries) and none of them actually helped me.

```py
import smbus
import time

# Adres I2C czujnika SHT35
SHT35_ADDRESS = 0x44

# Inicjalizacja magistrali I2C
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)  # Numer magistrali I2C (0 lub 1, w zależności od modelu Raspberry Pi)
time.sleep(1)
def read_sda_scl_status():
    try:
        sda_status = bus.read_byte(SHT35_ADDRESS)
        scl_status = bus.read_byte_data(SHT35_ADDRESS, 0x00)
        return sda_status, scl_status
    except Exception as e:
        print("Błąd odczytu danych z magistrali I2C:", e)
        return None, None

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            sda_status, scl_status = read_sda_scl_status()
            if sda_status is not None and scl_status is not None:
                print(f"Stan SDA: {sda_status}")
                print(f"Stan SCL: {scl_status}")
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Przerwano przez użytkownika")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: yea, it has intendations, but I don't know why It copied without them